# Editing a datagrid by opening a modal dialog box

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I want to open a dialog box with some questions when I click on a column in a Flex Datagrid. After the dialog is closed, I want to fill that cell with information from the dialog.

What I have until now is this:

```
        public function startEdit(event:DataGridEvent):void {
            // event.dataField is null, so we figure it out ourselves
            var column:DataGridColumn = dgQObjects.columns[event.columnIndex];
            if (column.dataField == "parameters") {
                // depending on the type, we can fill in parameters
                var type:String = ListCollectionView(dgQObjects.dataProvider).getItemAt(event.rowIndex).type;
                switch(type) {
                    case "Gauge":
                        event.preventDefault();

                        quartzObjects[event.rowIndex].parameters = "foo";
                        updateLocalStorage();
                        dgQObjects.validateNow();
                        break;
                    case "Indicator":
                        break;
                    case "New Row":
                        event.preventDefault();
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
```

It sets the 'parameters' to 'foo', so that's good, but it doesn't show that in the datagrid (validateNow() does nothing). Also, if I put in an Alert(), the startEdit keep triggering, and I can never close the Alertbox. The grid is defined as follows:

```
  <QuartzUI:DoubleClickDataGrid width="800" x="10" y="10" height="337" 
             id="dgQObjects"
             editable="true"
             itemEditBegin="{startEdit(event)}"
             itemEditEnd="{checkQuartzObjects()}"
             creationComplete="{initDataGrid()}"
             >
```

(A DoublieClickDataGrid is a subclass of DataGrid)

Comment: Apparently there is also a itemEditBeginning, that works a little different. If I use that, the datagrid gets updated.

Comment: I've said this a few times already: there usually is no reason to subclass DataGrid, unless you want to modify its core functionality (opening a popup on doubleclick is definitely not a suitable candidate).

Comment: The doubleclick is on editing the fields, and in the case of this column, it opens a dialog. My question is not related to the doubleclick, but to the updating of the grid.

Comment: I realize that; it was just meant as an advice. You can easily implement that behavior without subclassing DataGrid, as you can see in my answer.

Comment: @RIAstar ah. OK, thanks. I found this doubleclickdatagrid somewhere and just threw it in my project. As it did what I needed, I never bothered to do it another way.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this through data binding on the model object. It'll make your life a lot easier. Assume the following DataGrid:

```
<s:DataGrid id="dg" dataProvider="{dp}" 
            doubleClickEnabled="true" 
            doubleClick="editSelectedItem()">

    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="name" />
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

`doubleClickEnabled` is `false` by default, so we have to set it explicitly to be able to catch the `doubleClick` events. Now let's have a look at the `editSelectedItem()` method:

```
private function editSelectedItem():void {
    var popup:MyEditor = new MyEditor();
    popup.data = dg.selectedItem as MyClass;
    PopUpManager.addPopUp(popup, this, true);
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popup);
}
```

We just create a new view and pass it the currently selected datagrid item. Then we open it as a modal popup. (note that I haven't added any code to close the popup again to keep my example as simple as possible). Now the MyEditor view looks like this:

```
<s:Panel xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:m="net.riastar.model.*"
         title="Edit label"
         width="400" height="300" >

    <fx:Declarations>
        <m:MyClass id="data" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:TextInput text="@{data.name}" />

</s:Panel>
```

We use two-way data binding to edit the `name` property of the `MyClass` instance (note that this property must be marked `Bindable` for this to work). This is enough for a working example: if you now edit the value in the TextInput, you'll see the according value change in the DataGrid in the background.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, there is a 'type' column in my datagrid and I need a different popup per type. So I edit all columns 'inline' in the datagrid, and only one column makes a popup come up.

Comment: @BartFriederichs In that case, just replace the `doubleClick` event handler with something like `gridDoubleClick="editSelectedItem(event.columnIndex)"` and use the column index to filter out the column you want a popup for. The binding method remains the same.